# What is the file path structure to connect Jenkins with local Git repository for the Pipeline script?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What is the file path structure to connect Jenkins with local Git repository for the Pipeline script?

I have linked the Pipeline SCM with repository using the URL: `file:///home/user/git/` , but when I try to put in the script path for the Pipeline script, `./Jenkinsfile`, an error occurs. A FileNotFoundException is thrown. How would I fix this? I do not want to create a absolute file path from a certain users git repository. I want to have a file path only from the git repository.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the checkout work?  Is the Jenkinsfile in the root directory of the git repo?  What if you leave off the "./" and just use "Jenkinsfile" for the path to the pipeline script?

Comment: I tried to leave off the `./` in the path. I still go the same error. How would I know if the checkout worked? Does that mean in the changes window, all of the files from the repo. would be reported as a "New File"?

Comment: A workaround might be moving the directory under the jenkins workspace folder, though i doubt you would like to do it for long term

Also, try checking the git polling (for pipeline project) or scan (for multibranch pipeline) log, that may give more information.

Comment: Exactly. The idea is for other user to only need the clone the git repo. and then be able to use Jenkins for builds and test by having access the to the Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into similar issues running jenkins from a docker container. Try omitting user and file:// from your path.

```
/home/git/
```

I found this by executing:

```
docker exec -it jenkins-container bash
ls /home
```